# Create variable with many types in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, generics, types

I have a struct and in this struct I have variable that I want to be of any type `UITextField` of `UIButton`. I think I can use generics somehow. 
So, my code looks like this

```
private struct ValidationObject {
    var textField: RITextFieldLine
        ...
}
```

`textField` variable with type `RITextFieldLine` is my custom view. But I don't want it to be of this specific type.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: make it AnyObject

Comment: You could use `UIView` or `UIControl`.  You could also add your own protocol `Validateable` and then add this protocol to various control types via an extension; As @Sweeper asked, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Lu_ That's bad advice, seriously.

Comment: Thanks. I have instance of this struct inside of method an later I want to be able to pass textField or UIButton to variable.  `func addValidationTo(field textField: RITextFieldLine, type validationType: ValidationType, errorMessage errorMsg: String) {
        let object = ValidationObject(textField: textField, type: validationType, errorMessage: errorMsg)
        validationObjectsArray.append(object)
    }`

Comment: @Sulthan just like overal idea of doing what he described

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you use a protocol to define `Validateable`.  You can then apply this protocol to any required class via an extension:

```
protocol Validateable {}

extension UITextField: Validateable {}

extension UIButton: Validateable {}

extension AnyOtherTypeYouLike: Validateable {}
```

Then you can use it in your struct

```
private struct ValidationObject {
   var validationItem: Validateable
    ...
}
```

You can also use the protocol to define any functions that should be implemented by a `Validateable` object and the extension to implement them.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to assign are view elements then:

```
private struct ValidationObject {
    var textField: UIView
        ...
}
```

Otherwise:

```
private struct ValidationObject {
    var textField: Any
        ...
}
```

Considering your property naming (textField), I'd say go with the first one. Just remember to use this when you a want to use the variable as a specific type:

```
if let textField = validationObjectInstance.textField as? RITextFieldLine {
    textField.someMethodOrProperty
}
```